# Listdir not finding all files inside loop

Tags: python, windows, for-loop, listdir

I have a code that do some transformation in some files, for a range of years and quarterly/semiannually. Here is the code:

```
year = ['2017', '2018', '2019', '2020']
for y in year:
    onlyfiles1 = [file for file in listdir('prev_dir/'+y+'/detailed') if isfile(join('prev_dir/'+y+'/detailed', file))]
    onlyfiles2 = [file for file in listdir('prev_dir/'+y+'/old') if isfile(join('prev_dir/'+y+'/old', file))]  
    if len(onlyfiles2) < len(onlyfiles1):
        onlyfiles2.append('')
    for i, j in zip(onlyfiles1, onlyfiles2):
        print(i, j)
        function_transform(i, j, 'prev_dir/final'+i, y)
```

It was working correctly last quarter, but now that in 2020 has a new file it won't read the last file.

If I run only to check if the files are readable:

```
[file for file in listdir('prev_dir/'+y+'/detailed') if isfile(join('prev_dir/'+y+'/detailed', file))]
Out: ['1_qua_2020.xlsx', '2_qua_2020.xlsx']
```

All years, except 2020, has a file in 'old' folder that is used by one of the functions inside function_transform. When I run the code it iterate through the years and folders correctly, except for the last file '2_qua_2020.xlsx', as you can see below:

```
1_sem_2017.xlsx 1o_sem_2017.xlsx        #files in 'detailed' and 'old' folder
data_transf/final_1_sem_2017.xlsx       #name of saved file
392780                                  #len df
2_sem_2017.xlsx 2o_sem_2017.xlsx
data_transf/final_2_sem_2017.xlsx 
340522
1_sem_2018.xlsx 1o_sem_2018.xlsx
data_transf/final_1_sem_2018.xlsx 
380199
2_sem_2018.xlsx 2o_sem_2018.xlsx
data_transf/final_2_sem_2018.xlsx 
370914
1_sem_2019.xlsx 1_sem_19_at.xlsx
data_transf/final_1_sem_2019.xlsx 
595040
2_sem_2019.xlsx 
data_transf/final_2_sem_2019.xlsx 
540177
1_qua_2020.xlsx 
data_transf/final_1_qua_2020.xlsx 
350119
```

I run some tests and if 'detailed' folder has more than 2 files than 'old' folder it will not work. Independently if I use 'if' statement from the code. Hope you guys could enlighten me what I could be doing wrong.

*Files in 'detailed' folder I get from another code from the database.

Thanks!

Comment: I notice a hacky approach to try to expand the `list`s to match size. Maybe try using `itertools.zip_longest` instead of `zip` to make sure you're handling cases where the sizes don't just differ by one in length?

Comment: @ShadowRanger well that solved my problem =). Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't know about `itertools.zip_longest`.